# Why does beta particles deviate more than alpha particles?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, mass, radioactivity

So two figures are given in my book,
One is Deflection of radioactive radiations in magnetic field

[image]

and the other is deflection of radiations in an electric field

[image]

So the question is why does beta particles deflect more than alpha particles?
And why does this deflection increases in electric field ?

Comment: Charge and mass differences

Comment: The scale is totally wrong with the deflection of an $\alpha$ being much less than that of a $\beta$. The $\alpha$ has twice the charge but $7300$ times the mass.

Comment: @Farcher but is'nt the angle of α deflection much smaller because it is heavier for the same momentum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\alpha$ particles are composed by 2 neutrons and 2 protons, they have a charge of $Q_{\alpha} = +2e$ and a mass of $m_{\alpha} = 6.6 \cdot 10^{-27}$ kg. Their mass to charge ratio, therefore is $\frac{m_{\alpha}}{Q_{\alpha}} = 2.1 \cdot 10^{-8} \frac{kg}{C}$.
As you can see, due to their positive charge, they are attracted to the lowest potential of the electric field (the "-").

On the other hand, $\beta$ particle are electrons (they can also be positrons but in you picture they are attracted to the highest potential in the electric filed).
Electrons have a charge of $Q_e = -e$ and a mass of $m_e = 9.1 \cdot 10^{-31}$ kg.
Their mass to charge ratio is $5.7 \cdot 10^{-12} \frac{kg}{C}$.

If you consider these mass to charge ratio, you notice that the value for $\alpha$ particle is much bigger that for the $\beta$.

Now consider a particle with mass $m$ and charge $Q$ that travels trough a uniform magnetic field with speed $V$. We have to equate Lorentz force with centripetal force:
$$
\frac{mV^2}{r} = QVB \implies r = \frac{m}{Q}\frac{V}{B}
$$

And notice that $\frac{m}{Q}$ is the dominant factor of difference since the magnetic field $B$ is constant for both particles.
Here you could argue that the speed $V$ can be dominant but in most nuclear decay it is not. Feel free to correct me on this point on the comments.

Anyway, the key fact is that $r$ is linearly dependent form the mass to charge ratio and the different nature of these two particles influence how much they "curve" when entering a magnetic field. In particular, the radius for $\alpha$ will be much bigger when compared to $\beta$ particles.

Comment: Most excellent. welcome to the physics SE.